# FlutterBloc Repository Provider Extending a Singleton Class

Tags: flutter, repository, bloc, flutter-bloc

First of all, I am open to new ideas.

I provide a HomeRepository at the beginning of the application using RepositoryProvider. I will need the properties listed in this repository in most of the pages of the application. **I don't want to fetch** all these in different pages.

```
class HomeRepository {
  Dio? dio;
  DioClient? dioC;

  List<RelationType>? _relationTypes;
  List<BusinessField>? _businessFieldList;
  List<AddressType>? _addressTypeList;
  List<City>? _cityList;
  List<Country>? _countryList;
  List<Gender>? _genderList;

  HomeRepository._() {
    dio = Dio();
    if (dio != null) {
      dioC = DioClient(dio!);
    }
  }

   .... FetchFunctions() ...
```

For example when I navigate to CompanyPage,
I create a new instance of CompanyRepository:

```
class CompanyRepository extends HomeRepository{}
```

It causes to re-creating HomeRepository again and that's why all the properties are null as expected.

How can I deal with it?
Is it a good idea to create a singleton repository for such cases?

Answer (score 0):

**The singleton example from you class HomeRepository :**

```
class HomeRepository {
          Dio? dio;
          DioClient? dioC;
        
          List<RelationType>? _relationTypes;
          List<BusinessField>? _businessFieldList;
          List<AddressType>? _addressTypeList;
          List<City>? _cityList;
          List<Country>? _countryList;
          List<Gender>? _genderList;
        
          // Singleton instance
          static final HomeRepository _instance = HomeRepository._();
        
          factory HomeRepository() {
            return _instance;
          }
        
          HomeRepository._() {
            dio = Dio();
            if (dio != null) {
              dioC = DioClient(dio!);
            }
          }
        
          // ... FetchFunctions() ...
        }
```

Comment: Now, How am I supposed to define CompanyRepository?
class CompaniesRepository extends HomeRepository {}
Says:
The unnamed constructor of superclass 'HomeRepository' (called by the default constructor of 'CompaniesRepository') must be a generative constructor, but factory found. (Documentation)  Try adding an explicit constructor that has a different superinitializer or changing the superclass constructor 'HomeRepository HomeRepository()' to not be a factory constructor.

Comment: class CompanyRepository extends HomeRepository {
  CompanyRepository(): super._();
}

Comment: I tried that as well but I got : The class 'HomeRepository' doesn't have a constructor named '_'. (Documentation)  Try defining a constructor named '_' in 'HomeRepository', or invoking a different constructor

Comment: I do not know what you want to achieve here. because if you extend the singleton class to a new class (subclass), when the subclass is created it will create a new instance not the instance from the superclass. Then, sugged you to have difference approach here, like using dependency injection.